# Reading, Returning, and Writing on Text Files in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am stuck on a error that I cant seem to figure out. The program I made should ask the user for a text file and number. The program than searches the text file for that number, if it exists it should find all of its occurrences and return their line numbers. If it it doesn't it should add the number to the text file. Think you can help me?

I have already created the users input and a if statement of what should happen if found.

This is what I have:

```py
import linecache

def Q10(name, number):

    with open(name) as infile:

        contents = infile.read()

        if number in contents:

            line_number = linecashe.getline(name, number)

            print(number, "was found on line", line_number)

Q10('Q10.txt', 56)
```

This is the error that I got:

```py
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Comment: Could you show us how you're calling `Q10`? The error seems to suggest that `number` might be an `int` rather than a `string`, so you might have to do a conversion before the `if` statement.

Comment: Q10('Q10.txt', 56)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57151761/edit) your question and put it there. It will be a lot more useful for people trying to help you than having them search through the comments. That said, you're passing `56` in for the `number` parameter. Try passing it as a string (`"56"`) or converting it in `Q10`. I'm no python expert and I'm afraid I couldn't tell you how to do it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

number is an int, you need to convert it to string.
you can do it with str(int) as I showed in the code

```
import linecache

def Q10(name, number):

    with open(name) as infile:

        contents = infile.read()

        if str(number) in contents:

            line_number = linecashe.getline(name, number)

            print(number, "was found on line", line_number)

Q10('Q10.txt', 56)
```